# Fat Free failed to catch Axios FormData with file upload

Tags: javascript, fat-free-framework, axios

I use Axios to do AJAX request to Fat Free.

Here's the reciever code:

```php
$files = \Web::instance()->receive(function($file){
    var_dump($file);
    return (substr($file["type"],0,6)=="image/");
}, true);
if($files===false)
    throw new \Exception\UnexpectedInput("U didn't provide any file");
```

and here's the sender (currently i use Axios to do the job.)

```js
return new Promise((ok,err)=>{
    var datanya = new FormData();
    datanya.append(this.generateRandomString(), new Blob([file[0]], {type:"image/jpeg"}), "image.jpg");
    // generate id for cancelation.
    this.uploadCancelSource = CancelToken.source();
    var config = {
        cancelToken: this.uploadCancelSource.token,
        onUploadProgress:(e)=>{
            this.uploadProgress = Math.round( (e.loaded * 100) / e.total );
        }
    }
    APICall.put("invoice/bukti", datanya, config).then(e=>{
    });
});
```

The payload seems to be ok for me, i mean, it transmits filename, content type, and form name. But FatFree Web's Class didn't catch it. It just telling that it is a `application/octet-stream`.

Here's screenshoot for the payload

[image: Request Dumping SS]

And here's the dumped data from the `\Web::instance()->receive`

[image: Dumped data from server]

You know the problem?

Comment: This seems to be the `PUT` and `POST` issue, ref: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/master/lib/web.php#L173

https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2410898

I need to use `PUT` to give the file to server. :(

Comment: Why do you need a `PUT`? You can try to `$f3->VERB='POST'` just before calling `receive()` but that's an ugly hack..

Comment: depends on the clientside upload implementation. I had to use `$f3->VERB='POST'` too for a blueimp jquery uploader once before and it was working quite well. looks a little hackish but if the uploader doesn't follow common conventions, it's a reasonable hack IMO.

Comment: Tahnkyou @xfra35 and @ikkez! I think i'll change the request method, just to make sure that it wont broke at further releases hahahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current behavior of class `Web` are the main problem. As you can see at the [source code](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/master/lib/web.php#L173), or see the [documentation](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/web#receive), it has different behaviour on different request method.

A little hacking, can be used to fix the current problem, but i decided to change the request method.